# listing current working directory when seeing all open shells in a screen session

Tags: gnu-screen

I use screen and start a couple of shells within it. Now, if I list all shells using Ctrl-a " , then, all the windows are listed with a generic "bash" label. How can I change this, for e.g. so that they also list the current working directory of that window also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I figured it out. What is displayed via the Ctrl-A " sequence is the xterm window name, so you have to set that to something else.

So, for bash, put this in the .bashrc

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='
if [ $TERM = "screen" ]; then
echo -n -e "\033k$MYPWD\033\\"
fi
'
```

Comment: I have exactly the same need, but I don't understand your solution ! What represent $MYPWD ? I assume that some where you have MYPWD = `pwd` ... is it dynamically updated ? and you change the prompt, not the 'xterm window name' ?